# Npgsql not returning latest row

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am writing an application which polls postgresql DB to check for new rows inserted by another application. Most of the time everything works, but once in a while something "hangs". Even though newer record exists in database, an application reads second-latest row.

Polling is realised by following code

```cs
private async Task<ResultRow> RetreiveLastRow() {
    ResultRow row = null;

    var connectionString = "server=<ip>;user id=<user>;password=<pass>;database=<db name>";
    using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT <fields> FROM <table> ORDER BY <field> DESC LIMIT 1";
        using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
            if (await reader.ReadAsync()) {
                row = <read row>;
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    return row;
}
```

Method above is called in loop every ~100ms.

```cs
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
    try {
        var lastRow = await RetreiveLastRow();

        Logger.Trace($"Last row id = {lastRow.Id}");
        // rest of code...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.Error(e, "Error");
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
}
```

I know for sure that there is newer record in a database. I can see it with PgAdmin, but my application is does not see what I see.

Everything is back to normal when yet another row is added to table - an application sees newest data (for some time). After awhile, when new records are added to table, problem reappears.

I suspect that query result is cached by a driver and is not refreshed from db. So I tried to turn off connection polling by adding "polling=false" to connection string (which should disable caching, if there is any). It seems to resolve the problem, but I am not entirely sure.

Is this really caching problem? If it is, can it be solved without turning off connection polling?

Comment: Npgsql doesn't have any sort of query caching - whenever you execute a command it gets sent to the database and executed. Are you sure your newly-inserted row isn't in an uncommitted transaction (and so not yet visible in other connections)?

Comment: Regardless, what you're doing may be achieved better with triggers and Npgsql Wait(), rather than polling. Note that with your method you may miss rows off they're inserted quickly (i.e. 2 rows within the polling window).

Comment: Finally, if you want to keep your current design you should probably just keep a single connection open for the lifetime of the application and reuse it rather than reopening. You can also prepare your polling command for slightly better performance.

Comment: I am not sure if it's uncommitted transaction, but another software (namely PgAdmin) sees new row, so my guess is that it is committed. `connection.Close()` does not close connection, but merely returns it to the pool provided by npgsql, so current code should benefit from single connection. Your suggestion to use `Wait` method is very interesting. I had no clue that was possible. I will give it a try for sure. Question still stands: what could be the reason, that my way sometimes does not work?

Comment: Just to make sure - the new row isn't added from the sane pgadmin that is used to check that the row has been inserted, is it? Otherwise it could again be a simple matter of an uncommitted transaction. If not, and your pgadmin is seeing a new row whereas your Npgsql app isn't, then it's very likely there's some issue with your application code - the SQL query or something else (which I can't know without seeing the entire code etc.)

Comment: Record is inserted by an external application which I do not control and don't have access to. Code i pretty much what I wrote in post. Query is executed, row is read and then turned into an object. An `id` field of an object is printed out to stdout. I can observe that it is not changing despite of new row being inserted into the table. If you want more specific information please tell me what you want to know. I will try my best to answear.

Comment: I can't really guess what's going on. My only advice would be to turn on statement logging at the PostgreSQL side (or at least in Npgsql) to make sure everything is happening as you're expecting it too. Ideally you would also be able to catch the situation right after a new row is inserted and not seen by your app, pause the producing app (freezing the situation) and investigate exactly what's going on. I'm betting it's something silly and unexpected as opposed to an actual serious problem somewhere.